# How to split text into "steps" using regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to split texts into "steps"
Lets say my text is

```
my $steps = "1.Do this. 2.Then do that. 3.And then maybe that. 4.Complete!"
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
"1.Do this."
"2.Then do that."
"3.And then maybe that."
"4.Complete!"
```

I'm not really that good with regex so help would be great!

I've tried many combination like:

```
split /(\s\d.)/
```

But it splits the numbering away from text

Comment: Use a lookahead, `/\s+(?=\d.)/`

Answer (score 4):

I would indeed use `split`. But you need to exclude the digit from the match by using a lookahead.

```perl
my @steps = split /\s+(?=\d+\.)/, $steps;
```

Answer (score 3):

All step-descriptions start with a number followed by a period and then have non-numbers, until the next number. So capture all such patterns

```
my @s = $steps =~ / [0-9]+\. [^0-9]+ /xg; 

say for @s;
```

This works only if there are surely no numbers in the steps' description, like any approach relying on matching a number (even if followed by a period, for decimal numbers)<sup>†</sup>

If there may be numbers in there, we'd need to know more about the structure of the text.

Another delimiting pattern to consider is punctuation that ends a sentence (`.` and `!` in these examples), if there are no such characters in steps' description and there are no multiple sentences

```
my @s = $steps =~ / [0-9]+\. .*? [.!] /xg;
```

Augment the list of patterns that end an item's description as needed, say with a `?`, and/or `."` sequence as punctuation often goes inside quotes.<sup>‡</sup>

If an item can have multiple sentences, or use end-of-sentence punctuation mid-sentence (as a part of a quotation perhaps) then tighten the condition for an item's end by combining footnotes -- end-of-sentence punctuation *and* followed by number+period

```
my @s = $steps =~ /[0-9]+\. .*? (?: \."|\!"|[.\!]) (?=\s+[0-9]+\. | \z)/xg;
```

If this isn't good enough either  then we'd *really* need a more precise description of that text.

---

<sup>†</sup> An approach using a "numbers-period" pattern to delimit item's description, like

```
/ [0-9]+\. .*? (?=\s+[0-9]+\. | \z) /xg;
```

(or in a lookahead in `split`) fails with text like

`1. Only $2.50`   or   `1. Version 2.4.1`   ...

---

<sup>‡</sup> To include text like `1. Do "this."` and `2. Or "that!"` we'd want

```
/ [0-9]+\. .*? (?: \." | !" | [.!?]) /xg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following sample code demonstrates power of regex to fill up `%steps` hash in one line of code.

Once the data obtained you can dice and slice it anyway your heart desires.

Inspect the sample for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my($str,%steps,$re);

$str   = '1.Do this. 2.Then do that. 3.And then maybe that. 4.Complete!';
$re    = qr/(\d+)\.(\D+)\./;
%steps = $str =~ /$re/g;

say Dumper(\%steps);

say "$_. $steps{$_}" for sort keys %steps;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 'Do this',
          '2' => 'Then do that',
          '3' => 'And then maybe that'
        };

1. Do this
2. Then do that
3. And then maybe that
```

Comment: This fails unless there is a terminating dot (e.g. with "!").  Also fails with lines like "5. And 1-more."

Comment: In fact, see the explanation @zdim provided with his code posted yesterday.

Comment: @JRFerguson Is it too difficult to adjust `$re` to process the input data accordingly? I do not think that it is too difficult task. The code is a just a sample as it assumes that input data can be whatever OP will feed in and OP would make required changes to adjust `$re` to accommodate input data.